# Automated email Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Someone was kind enough a while ago to share with me a script that allowed me to send myself an email automatically as long as I had a time trigger. Yesterday, Google changed the OAuth in Apps Script and it doesn't work anymore. I was wondering if someone may teach me how to update the script I have been using.

Google Changes to OAuth in Apps Script: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/03/changes-to-oauth-in-apps-script.html

Below is the script I have been using:

```
///////////////

function readCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Overview");  
  var value = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
  if(value>=10) sendEmail(value);
};

function sendEmail(value) {
  var email = "ENTERYOUREMAILHERE";
  var subject = "Vanguard Target Allocation Alert: " + value+"%";
  var body = "This is an automatically generated email to inform you that your Vanguard accounts off of your target allocation by " + value + "%";

  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body); 

};

///////////////
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need OAuth for sending a simple mail from Google Script. You remove the deprecated part from your script and it should continue to work.

```
function sendEmail(value) {

  var email = "ENTERYOUREMAILHERE";
  var subject = "Vanguard Target Allocation Alert: " + value+"%";
  var body = "This is an automatically generated email to inform you that your Vanguard accounts off of your target allocation by " + value + "%";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body); 

};
```

Comment: Amit,

I forgot to update this when I figured it out a few days ago; I did it exactly like you did!

I appreciate it, thank you.